# npm install does not work for aws-sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm

I'm trying to install aws-sdk and it fails with a "shasum check failed..." error. I tried it on a a windows and a linux machines, same result, exactly the same checksum mismatch.

Using "npm install aws-sdk" command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to these guys through twitter, and they were able to resolve the issue.  I was able to verify that it works now.

see: https://twitter.com/seldo/statuses/468907735845994497

Comment: What was the solution?